# How to load Angular component based selected on radio button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm learning currently Angular. I use the Angular reactive form to implement my forms. I want to display the login button or registration component based on the selected radio button.

```
export class IdentificationComponent implements OnInit {

  identificationForm: FormGroup;
  yesNo: boolean[] = [true, false];
  hasAccount: boolean = true;

  constructor(private _announcementService: AnnouncementService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.identificationForm = new FormGroup({
      'hasAccount': new FormControl(this.hasAccount, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  changeIdentificationType(event: any){
   this.hasAccount = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

here the template

```
<form [formGroup]="identificationForm">
  <label>Do you already have an account?</label>
  <label *ngFor="let v of yesNo">
    <span *ngIf="v; else no">Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="hasAccount" [value]="v" (change)="changeIdentificationType($event)">
  </label>
</form>

<div *ngIf="hasAccount; else registration">
  <app-login></app-login>
</div>

<ng-template #registration>
  <app-registration></app-registration>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #no>No</ng-template>
```

Unfortunately, When selecting the radio button noting happens. How to load or show only the specific component based on the radio button?

Comment: Use `<div *ngIf="!hasAccount"></div>` instead of `ng-template` for your registration component. If the ngIf evaluates to false, it will not render the component, you don't lose anything. It's also more readable, but that's my opinion.

Comment: It doesn't work. It always renders the login component when `hasAccount ` is set to `true` as the initial value and the registration component when it is to `false`. which means that `*ngIf` directive cannot react on changes.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It does what it's meant to do, displaying either your login or registration component, based on the value of `hasAccount`. Please provide a reproducible example with an explanation of what is in your opinion not working as intended, for example on stackblitz.

Comment: When I click on the "Yes" radio button, I expect only the login component to be displayed, and when I click on "No" only the registration component should be displayed. At the moment, `{{ hasAccount }}` returns the expected output based on the selected radio button but the displayed component only depends on the `initial` value of `account` in the typescript file. I want the display of components to react on my radio button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xb3lze) You can use number 1 0 rather then true false for `hasAccount`

```
<div *ngIf="hasAccount==1; else registration">
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. It solves my issues. The was the datatype chooses. For a reason, I don't now `boolean` can not be bound properly when combined with *ngIf directive.

Answer (score 0):

Reference it in the template via identificationForm.get('hasAccount').value:

```
<div *ngIf="identificationForm.get('hasAccount').value; else registration">
```

EDIT:
When you define your formControl, don't surround the controlname with quotes. (note: **hasAccount**)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.identificationForm = new FormGroup({
      hasAccount: new FormControl(this.hasAccount, Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `{{ hasAccount }}`  on the template returns the expected output based on the selected button. `{{ identificationForm.get('hasAccount').value }}` doesn't. In both cases, the *ngIf directive doesn't work.