# Using multiple ng-content with ngIf does not work

Tags: angular

I have a situation where I need to display some content passed via `ng-content` with a selector to one of two areas. I have an `ngIf` that is used to check where to render the `ng-content`. The problem is that even if I have an `ngIf` in my first `ng-content`, the content will not be rendered in the second `ng-content` even if the condition for the first one is false. Here's an example of the issue:

```
<div>
    <ng-content *ngIf="someBoolean" select="figure"></ng-content>
    <div *ngIf="!someBoolean">
        <ng-content select="figure"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine if `someBoolean` is true. However, nothing will be inside the second `div` if `someBoolean` is false. What can I do to fix this? I found these two similar questions, but I tried all solutions and it does not work with Angular 6:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22972#issuecomment-407358396
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727533/10002144
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699654/10002144

Before you lock my question, I guarantee that I have tried all these solutions and they do not work on Angular 6 if you use selectors in `ng-content`.

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044104/how-to-load-angular-component-based-selected-on-radio-button/62045763#62045763

Comment: @pc_coder Unfortunately, this does not concern my issue.

Comment: Hello @ThomasFromUganda are you checked this example? https://ng-run.com/edit/N7cnnC9HCm1cKlE88QFp?open=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I have, but if you actually put a selector for the `ng-content`, you will see that it stops working.

Comment: yes but you need to put the content with your selector

Comment: look in your case the `select="figure"` that means you need to put your data something like this `<your-component-where-is-the-ng-select><figure>the content</figure></your-component-where-is-the-ng-select>`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Yes, this is exactly what I am doing. If you take the example you linked me, add a selector for `ng-content` in comp.component.html and then add that selector in app.component.html, it will not working anymore. Try it out.

Comment: strage it is working on my side, here is the screenshots, sorry I couldn't find a way to fork the project

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `<comp><ng-template>ur content</ng-template></comp>` and in `comp` get the `NgTemplateOutlet` via `@ContentChild` and then to use `ngIf` along with `ngTemplateOutlet`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bswj6Sgtxzi6B7I5qe4mMdlgODXWOyvh/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5PNNwIWfRM6D4LUGO7uVM0VwhiF88w5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Apologies everyone, I was using PUG and for some reason the ID of the `ng-template` wasn't working properly.